# longjmp and RAII

Tags: c++, raii, signal-handling, setjmp

So I have a library (not written by me) which unfortunately uses `abort()` to deal with certain errors. At the application level, these errors are recoverable so I would like to handle them instead of the user seeing a crash. So I end up writing code like this:

```
static jmp_buf abort_buffer;
static void abort_handler(int) {
    longjmp(abort_buffer, 1); // perhaps siglongjmp if available..
}

int function(int x, int y) {

    struct sigaction new_sa;
    struct sigaction old_sa;

    sigemptyset(&new_sa.sa_mask);
    new_sa.sa_handler = abort_handler;
    sigaction(SIGABRT, &new_sa, &old_sa);

    if(setjmp(abort_buffer)) {
        sigaction(SIGABRT, &old_sa, 0);
        return -1
    }

    // attempt to do some work here
    int result = f(x, y); // may call abort!

    sigaction(SIGABRT, &old_sa, 0);
    return result;
}
```

Not very elegant code. Since this pattern ends up having to be repeated in a few spots of the code, I would like to simplify it a little and possibly wrap it in a reusable object. My  first attempt involves using RAII to handle the setup/teardown of the signal handler (needs to be done because each function needs different error handling). So I came up with this:

```
template <int N>
struct signal_guard {
    signal_guard(void (*f)(int)) {
        sigemptyset(&new_sa.sa_mask);
        new_sa.sa_handler = f;
        sigaction(N, &new_sa, &old_sa);
    }

    ~signal_guard() {
        sigaction(N, &old_sa, 0);
    }
private:
    struct sigaction new_sa;
    struct sigaction old_sa;
};


static jmp_buf abort_buffer;
static void abort_handler(int) {
    longjmp(abort_buffer, 1);
}

int function(int x, int y) {
    signal_guard<SIGABRT> sig_guard(abort_handler);

    if(setjmp(abort_buffer)) {
        return -1;
    }

    return f(x, y);
}
```

Certainly the body of `function` is **much** simpler and more clear this way, but this morning a thought occurred to me. **Is this guaranteed to work?** Here's my thoughts:

1. No variables are volatile or change between calls to `setjmp`/`longjmp`.
2. I am `longjmp`ing to a location in the same stack frame as the `setjmp` and `return`ing normally, so I am allowing the code to execute the cleanup code that the compiler emitted at the exit points of the function.
3. It appears to work as expected.

But I still get the feeling that this is likely undefined behavior. What do you guys think?

Comment: Why are you not using a C++ exception?  It trivially solves your problem.

Comment: @Hans - http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801?ciid=c5080055abe021100055abe02110275d6e10RCRD

Comment: @Hans: c++ exceptions don't catch `abort` calls.

Comment: throw them in your abort_handler(), this isn't different.

Comment: @Hans throwing exceptions in signal handlers is not guaranteed to work in all platforms and so is essentially not portable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that `f` is in a third party library/app, because otherwise you could just fix it to not call abort. Given that, and that RAII may or may not reliably produce the right results on all platforms/compilers, you have a few options.

- Create a tiny shared object that defines `abort` and LD_PRELOAD it. Then you control what happens on abort, and NOT in a signal handler.
- Run `f` within a subprocess. Then you just check the return code and if it failed try again with updated inputs.
- Instead of using the RAII, just call your original `function` from multiple call points and let it manually do the setup/teardown explicitly. It still eliminates the copy-paste in that case.

Comment: +1, I was thinking about adding interposing or thread/fork as a suggestion in my answer

Answer (score 3):

I actually like your solution, and have coded something similar in test harnesses to check that a target function `assert()`s as expected.

I can't see any reason for this code to invoke undefined behaviour.  The C Standard seems to bless it: handlers resulting from an `abort()` are exempted from the restriction on calling library functions from a handler. (Caveat: this is 7.14.1.1(5) of C99 - sadly, I don't have a copy of C90, the version referenced by the C++ Standard).

C++03 adds a further restriction: *If any automatic objects would be destroyed by a thrown exception transferring control to another (destination) point in the program, then a call to longjmp(jbuf, val) at the throw point that transfers control to the same (destination) point has undefined behavior.*  I'm supposing that your statement that 'No variables are volatile or change between calls to setjmp/longjmp' includes instantiating any automatic C++ objects. (I guess this is some legacy C library?).

Nor is POSIX async signal safety (or lack thereof) an issue - `abort()` generates its SIGABRT synchronously with program execution.

The biggest concern would be corrupting the global state of the 3rd party code: it's unlikely that the author will take pains to get the state consistent before an `abort()`.  But, if you're correct that no variables change, then this isn't a problem.

If someone with a better understanding of the standardese can prove me wrong, I'd appreciate the enlightenment.

Comment: I am fairly certain that no variables are changed. This is a C library, and it only aborts when it is asked to do an operation which requires it to `malloc` an obscene amount of space which is associated with the initialization of an opaque type). If it fails, then I can just consider than opaque type uninitialized and try to create a new one with more sane values.